# wrong file association .java file as objectiveC

Tags: java, android, android-studio

android studio show all kind of file types as c++ just for this project

i`v tried invalidate cache/restart, clean project, remove .gradle
but none of them working and steal showing wrong type
[related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TxzV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that [The latest version of Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) fixes this. [An issue has been opened previously.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173142942)

Comment: but no one find out any solution

Comment: I can't seem to find a solution but in the latest preview version the icons have been fixed. Click the first link in my original comment.

Comment: my problem is not just an icon , all of lines in editor are white and not indexing correct